# Formula to restrict number of characters of text field

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have a text field into list in sharepoint online, I want to know if there is a formula I can add to column format to only accept no more than 6 characters. or  there is some javascript or jquery to validate it? Regards

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the Column settings for the text field where you can specify the maximum characters.[image]

Or you can specify it in the column validation settings where you can set the formula and custom message 
[image]

Comment: Just a nit pic... The formula above can be shortened to `=LEN(UserName) < 7` as the expression is a Boolean that already returns true or false.